# How to I simplify an expression with two inequalities: if x <= y and x >= n

Tags: python, algorithm, comparison-operators, inequality

I have written this code to test the position of where something is relative to other things. It produces the results I want e.g `x = 4 -> True`, `x = 11 -> False`. But I was wondering how I can write this in a more pythonic way / one line.

```
x = 4
z = 5
y = z + 5
n = z - 5
if x <= y and x => n:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: You may be asking about chained operators `if n <= x <= y:` And in fact you don't need the `if` test - it will return a boolean, so just do `print(n <= x <= y)`. See also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/

Comment: Or you might mean `n < x < y` - there is inconsistency between your code and the question title as to whether the "or equal to" bit should be there or not. But in either case, you hopefully get the principle.

Comment: I’m not sure you objective of ‘one line’ is a good idea: strive for readable maintainable code not low line count. Nothing wrong with explicit simple conditions like you use.

Comment: @barny. Carrying "explicit" to an extreme is just as bad. I agree that OP's condition is completely legible, but the `if` statement itself is really and truly superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check that `x` is within some bound of `z`, use a simple difference and take the absolute value:

```
x = 4
z = 5
span = 5
print(abs(x - z) <= span)
```

In python, the result of a comparison operator is almost always a boolean. You don't need `if` to convert the result of your expression to a boolean. Print it directly instead.

If you don't want to call `abs` for some reason, you can use the fact that chained operators are implicitly combined with `and` in python:

```
print(z - span <= x <= z + span)
```

This is equivalent to your original code, as well as to

```
print(z - span <= x and x <= z + span)
```

The advantage of chaining the operators is that if you replace `x` with a complex expression, it will only be evaluated once in the first two examples I showed, but twice in the third one.

Comment: @barny. OP introduces two extra variables and a needless `if` statement that converts an already-bool quantity into a `bool`.

Comment: @barny. Keep in mind that you generally wouldn't need to print an intermediate quantity. You would act on it or return it to be acted on elsewhere. The clarity also has to do with your level of familiarity with python in general.

Comment: @barny. Finally, keep in mind that OP is specifically asking to write a one-liner if possible.

Comment: Definitely better then OP's; or for an "asymmetric" span, `z-5 <= x <= z+5`

Comment: @tobias_k. Sure, but why?

Comment: No particular reason. For a "symmetric" span, `abs` is nice, but maybe OP's case is more general. Also, might be worth just pointing out that comparison chaining is _possible_ in Python.

Comment: @tobias_k. I've added your suggestion with some commentary.

Answer (score -1):

This solution only works for integers, also it's the same amount of lines, the only difference is instead of two conditionals I used a list to check if x is inside of the range(n, y+1)

```
x = 4
z = 5
y = z + 5
n = z - 5
if x in range(n, y+1):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: That's true but the question is kind of abstract, I interpreted it as different to other languages.